# Fue vs. Era en situaciones específicas (trabajos)

Tags: gramática, verbos, cópulas

Tengo una pregunta sobre pretérito indefinido y pretérito de indicativo y hago prácticas con el verbo *ser*.

Entiendo que indefinido es para acciones o situaciones pasadas en un momento concreto y imperfecto es para hablar de acciones habituales.

No entiendo por qué estas son correctas:

- Picasso **fue** un gran artista y Marconi **fue** un gran inventor.

Pensé que debería usarse *era* porque no fue (?) un momento concreto.

Answer (score 3):

**Era** se usa se **algo que fue y dejo de ser**, algo que solia ser. Por ejemplo el precio de algo, una persona con ciertas cualidades:

Ejemplo de era:

1. La comida era mucho mejor. Implicas que fue buena y ya no lo es.
2. Lucy era una persona mas honesta. Implicas que lo fue pero ahora no.

**Fue** es algo que quedo en el pasado y termino y se recuerda de esta misma manera.

Ejemplo de fue.

1. Picasso fue un gran artista. Implica que en su momento lo fue y se recuerda como tal, es decir; nunca dejo de ser un gran artista.
2. Fue un placer haberte conocido. Implica que lo fue y se mantiene asi, como un recuerdo.

Answer (score 1):

Adicionalmente a la otra respuesta (que es muy buena), también existe una diferencia aspectual entre "fue" y "era". La persona puede no ser algo, o no ocupar algún cargo, o no tener algún trabajo, y utilizarse "fue" o "era" según se visualice el estado anterior como un hecho **puntual** o **durativo** en el pasado, respectivamente:

1. María **fue** profesora de español en 2021. (hecho puntual)
2. María **era** profesora de español en 2021. (situación durativa)

En ambos casos, María ya no es profesora de español. La diferencia es que en (1) visualizamos la acción como un hecho pasado ocurrido en 2021 (como si todo el año fuera un **punto en el tiempo**), mientras que en (2) hay un cierto énfasis en la duración de la acción, y podemos imaginar a María ejerciendo su profesión día tras día, o semana tras semana, durante todo el año 2021 (el año es más claramente percibido como un **período de tiempo**).